# ¿Como descargar un pdf en ajax?

Tags: ajax, mvc

Tengo un método que retorna un pdf

```
return File(stream, "application/pdf");
```

a este metodo lo invoco con ajax de la siguinte manera

```
  $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("HojaDeSalidaPDF")',
        data: { 'ID': id },
        type: "GET",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {

            //Descargar PDF

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, thrownError) {
            onFailure(xhr, status, thrownError);
        }
    });
```

mi duda es ¿como le puedo hacer para que me descargue el pdf?

Answer (score 1):

Una solución bastante fácil es añadir un link hacia dicho archivo y llamarlo, esta función es un ejemplo de como hacerlo.

Creamos un a con link al archivo (en el ejemplo es un link donde le pasamos los datos, es decir que podríamos hacer un "data:image,base64" y enviar a descargar una imagen que tengamos en base64 en alguna variable, etc), luego el nombre del archivo. Lo añadimos al dom, forzamos su click y lo quitamos del DOM. Fácil y para toda la familia.

```js
function descargarArchivo(uri, name) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = name;
  link.href = uri;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
  delete link;
}

descargarArchivo("data:text/html,HelloWorld!", "helloWorld.txt");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Nota ejemplo sacado de la respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15832662/3889570

Comment: me imagino que uri el la uri es la direccion del metodo que retorna el archivo?

Comment: Si, porejemplo "www.midominio.com/archivos/archivo.zip"